# IDPROPERTY IN STORES FOR COMBINED ID's

Tags: javascript, extjs, model, store

i will change my question. How do i set a combined id table(i mean a table with 2 columns as a primary key) as IDPROPERTY in a Model definition.

I'm Using Sencha Extjs 4.2.1.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Googling for a while i could find a solution maybe will help you if you want. Although you can not use Idproperty with combined keys(i mean more than one colum as a table key) as this article shows:

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?23168-CLOSED-IDProperty-set-multiple-key-fields

You can add a column for a temporal Id... and make this as type string and send it to server(it means we must work at server side for parsing the record or columns we would send). I take this article

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131785-Model-idProperty

I hope my research would help you. For me this question is solved, althougth anyone could have another idea.